# How to RDP and run commands in Windows EC2 Instance using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, devops

I would like to RDP into an Windows EC2 instance, and run some powershell commands on it.  How do I do it in boto3? For example: I need to create Windows user and Password in Windows EC2 Instance using Boto3 or Python Script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Boto3 SDK is only to manage AWS services, if you are looking for managing windows remotely from python try pywinrm library. WinRM is a windows remote management tool to invoke windows commands remotely. Documentation for pywinrm can be found in the following link.https://pypi.org/project/pywinrm/0.2.2/

You can also consider AWS systems manager:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/what-is-systems-manager.html

Comment: Yes. The "correct" way to do this in AWS is to use AWS Systems Manager Run Command to run a command on an Amazon EC2 instance, or even a whole fleet of instances.